# Azure limit on maximum IaaS instances per cloud service

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, iaas

We have a situation where we need 100 VMs inside the same cloud service. We have few doubts:

1. We have hit the limit of maximum number of IaaS instances per cloud service (50). Is this a soft limit that can be increased by contacting Azure support?
2. Is there any limit on maximum total outbound data throughput (or total internet connectivity speed) for a cloud service that we should be aware of?

Comment: Regarding limits: I'd open a billing ticket (which all subscription types allow you to do) to see if that can be changed. If not, there may be alternative architectural options, such as VNets, to circumvent this limit.

Answer (score 3):

We have contacted azure support and got the reply that this limit is by design.
We have now split the VMs across multiple cloud services inside the same virtual network to circumvent this limit for our scenario.